# String Concatenation Batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a batch script to compile all the files that are listed in a text file but I can't figure out how to concatenate a line on to the end of the pre existing variable.

Batch Script :

```
@echo off
SET files=

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (files.txt) do (
    SET files=%files% %1 %%a
)

echo %files%
pause
```

And this is files.txt :

```
Main.cpp
Player.cpp
```

At the moment running this outputs this : http://gyazo.com/5f397b818fee60a631a24e9efbca3abd.png

(I couldn't post image so if someone can I'd be grateful)

When it should output : "Main.cpp Player.cpp"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use **CALL** or **ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION** the value of your variable "Files" can't be re-assigned inside a **FOR** loop, also you are using the argument var **%1** wich is not necessary 'cause any argument is used/passed.

```
@Echo OFF

For /F "Usebackq Tokens=*" %%# in (
    "Files.txt"
) Do (
    Call Set "Files=%%Files%% %%#"
)

Echo Files = %Files%

Pause&Exit
```

**Files.txt content:**

```
test1.cpp
test2.cpp
test3.cpp
```

**Output:**

```
Files =  test1.cpp test2.cpp test3.cpp
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked straight off the bat!